# Как считать несколько строк с консоли в Java?

Tags: java, строки, консоль, scanner

Как считать несколько (количество может быть разное и мы НЕ можем его задать) строк с консоли в Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true){
    String current = scan.nextLine();
    if(current.equals(""))break;
    input.add(current);
}
```

Ввод прекращается когда введена пустая строка

Comment: вы же сами отвечали на подобный вопрос. зачем плодить дубликаты?

Comment: Человеческая память инструмент темный и слабо изученный. Вот я, например, в упор не помню, чтобы отвечал уже на такой вопрос. Что и не удивительно в виду его элементарности и времени потраченного на ответ

Comment: если вы посмотрите в колонку справа - **Связанные**, то увидите там похожие вопросы. это поможет вам вспомнить. а этот ответ стоит удалить.

Comment: Да по ссылке то я конечно прошел уже. Я про то, что в момент ответа я совершенно не помнил, что уже отвечал на подобное